# Trying to change style.top in div layer

Tags: javascript, styles

If an iPhone comes to my page I want to change the style.top position in a div layer. The code (document.getElementById('footer').style.top = "6550px";) below doesn't work. When I insert window.location = "openingfriday1.htm"; into the same position it works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks (and thanks to a user at 'stackoverflow' for the code).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        } };

if ( isMobile.Android() ) {
        window.location = "openingfriday1.htm";
}
else if(isMobile.iOS()) {
        document.getElementById('footer').style.top = "6550px";
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Looks fine to me, maybe it's not doing what you're expecting it to do because maybe it's an ... i don't know ... relative element? Make a fiddle with it containing the html as well maybe we can help then.

Comment: Make sure the `footer` has a `position` other than `static`, or else the `style.top` will not work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know it's not working because I want it to change the position from 6255px to 6550px. And it doesn't. See footer below. 

    <div id="footer" style="position: absolute; width: 900px; height: 1404px; z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 6255px">

Comment: Try !important for testing